# How to Connect database MySql using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I followed a lot of tutorial on google/youtube but still unable to connect database using php. I coded exactly according to documentation for database connection but it doesn,t work.I have already created database named as userregistration using mysql dashboard.
Here is myindex.html file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>User Login and Registration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-box">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 login-left">
            <h2>Login Here</h2>
            <form action="validation.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 login-right">
            <h2>Register Here</h2>
            <form action="registration.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Registration.php file:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'userregistration');
$name = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$s = "select * from  usertable where name='$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($num == 1){
    echo "Username Already Taken";
}else{
    $reg = "insert into usertable(name, password) values ('$name','$pass')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo "Registration Successful";
}
?>
```

Is there any error in my code?

Comment: Didn't work is not a very helpful error description, what message the website gave when you submit your registration form?

Comment: error shows(404 Not Found)

Comment: how do you structure your project? `action="registration.php"` say it will look for the file `registration.php` in the same folder of the HTML file

Comment: If you are on a *nix platform, file names are case sensitive as you have `registration.php` in your code and the file name you show as Registration.php (although this may be just in the question).

Comment: @NigelRen yeah this name is just in question. I,m using registration.php in small case in my project

Comment: @catcon I have not created folders. Just I created files. may be error exist in this action than how i can remove this error?

Comment: You have two nearly identical forms on the page.  Silly question but are you completing the right one when you test? The other one goes to validation.php. does that file exist in the correct location on your server? P.s. It's very hard to fix this kind of error without seeing the folder structure on the disk or the Apache config

Answer (score 1):

Try  using  directly the connection with db name

based on patter

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

try

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userregistration');
```

and be sure your php page is in the correct path
eventually try adding a proper path  or at least a relative path

```
   <form action="./Registration.php" method="post">
```

Comment: are you sure that username is localhost,, the password  is root and the db name is  
 userregistration  check better  ..anyway error 404 is not a db error but a page not found http error check for you link (and path) to the php page

Comment: You have missed the password out of the connect parameters.

Comment: no the username is not localhost. Servername is localhost, username is root, password is empy and database name is userregistration.

Comment: then adgiust the proper value in the right sequence  answer  updated ..

Comment: I also applied your updated code but again unfortunately it shows the same error when i click to register button(the error is 404 not found)

Comment: Error 404 is page not found .. check for the correct path..  your php name is Registration.php  not registration.php  ..be sure for proper case  ..  answer  updated

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP part looks alright. Maybe you can try to see if the PHP is able to make the connection by adding such a debugging code like how it is documented here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

```
if (!$con) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;
```

Finally, MOST IMPORTANTLY, you should probably not be using this directly because this can introduce serious SQL-Injection vulnerabilities. Google a little more about the best practices. :)